# monitor live microphone input

Tags: c#, vb.net, microphone

How can I monitor live microphone input?

I've read this site but that's only for recording:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cswavrec.aspx?df=90&fid=16677&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=3005817

How can I monitor it live? Or change the input volume?

I'm programming on Windows Vista with languages vb.net and c#.

Answer (score 3):

There's a codeproject article that could probably help you. The code is in C# and it mentions Vista. [Sound Activated Recorder with Spectrogram in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundCatcher.aspx). It seems like the same author has also posted another article called [Sound visualizer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundViewer.aspx) which might be helpful depending on what you mean with monitoring it live.